# Make hard drive stepper motor run 7200 rpm

Tags: stepper-motor, control-system

I have an old hard drive (7200 rpm) motor like this:

[image]

I'm trying to make it run as fast as possible and I start with this code (arduino uno):

```
int pin1 = 2;
int pin2 = 3;
int pin3 = 4;

int delay_time = 100;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin3, LOW);  
  delay(delay_time);

  digitalWrite(pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pin3, LOW);  
  delay(delay_time);

  digitalWrite(pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin3, HIGH);  
  delay(delay_time);
}
```

The motor runs when `delay_time` bigger than 50 (it run very slowly of course), with `delay_time` smaller it just "vibrate". So how can I make that runs at 7200 rpm?

**UPDATE:**

I use other source and some transistors for motor, not use arduino pins.

Comment: Microcontroller pins are not meant to drive motors, you need a driver device.  You may also need a higher voltage depending on winding inductance.  Are you sure that is actually a stepper, and not a BLDC motor intended for 3 phase sinusoudal drive between the windings?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I use other source and some transistors for motor, not arduino pins :(

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I think a BLDC motor should has 3 wires out, but here has 4.

Comment: Watch this video. I think it is in Dutch, but there are english subtitles available (You have to enable them).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMz2DYpos8w

Comment: Running HDD Motor using Sound Card of the PC https://youtu.be/R9Q1XrFZr5E

Comment: Try gradually decreasing delay_time instead of just starting it off at a low value.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run BLDC motor efficiently you need to know rotor position in relation to the winding(s). For sensored motor you will read sensors, for sensorless ( like this one ) you'd have to somehow read back EMF from the non-energized winding. The open-loop drive is very slow and you won't get any torque.

To know more about BLDC drive read Microchip appnote AN885.

BTW, you should've saved the controller to which this motor was initially attached; it can be used "off label" -> http://mightyohm.com/blog/2009/08/diamond-chop-saw-part-2/

Comment: Thanks you very very much. So, for now, I know that's not a stepper motor :D, but why BLDC like this need a common wire (I mean what's common wire used for? - sorry for my bad english)?

Comment: I don't know - did you measure anything?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if BLDCs suffer from the same 'notch' phenomena as steppers, but I'd imagine so. If it's not your problem, it's an interesting thing to note. At certain driving frequencies near the resonant frequency of the motor, there will be some audible vibrations, and the motor may not even move - it will just sit there and rumble even though it is getting 'valid' signals. Having said that, you could be having any number of issues with this.